# How to replace the last index value in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers `newArr`, whose length I use to create an array filled with zeros `zeroArr`

```js
const newArr = [1,3,5,8,9,3,7,13]
const zeroArr = Array.from(Array(newArr.length), () => 0);
console.log(zeroArr) // [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Now, I need to replace the last index value `0 to 10` so it should look like this:

```js
const result = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10]
```

How to do this?

Comment: `zeroArr[zeroArr.length-1] = 10`. I would suggest you to read basics of programming.

Comment: @void thanks for your reply, if i do this i will be getting `10`, but i need to replace the last index in my zeroArr array `result = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10]` like this.

Comment: Check the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the last item in the array like this:

```js
result[result.length-1] = 10;
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
const newArr = [1,3,5,8,9,3,7,13];
const zeroArr = Array.from(Array(newArr.length), () => 0); 
let result = zeroArr.slice(); // To create a copy
result[result.length-1] = 10;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: why not use `Array.fill()`?  `var zerroArr = newArr.fill(0);
zerroArr[zerroArr.length-1]=10;` will be executed faster.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and check if the last element, then return 10 otherwise zero.

```js
var array = [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 3, 7, 13],
    copy = array.map((_, i, a) => 10 * (i + 1 === a.length));
    
console.log(copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

another option could be:

```js
const newArr = [1,3,5,8,9,3,7,13]
const zeroArr = newArr.map(()=>0);
const arrWith10 = [...zeroArr.slice(0,-1), 10]
console.log(zeroArr) // [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
console.log(arrWith10) // [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10]
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to `copy` the values in the `newArr` to `zeroArr` first then `push` the value `10` to the `index` you wanted in `ZeroArr`. And `Print` to values in 'ZeroArr'