# How to reduce JS array length if next elements equal previous

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'd like to combine identical elements in an array, into a single term with how many times the value appears

```js
function combineArrayElements(arr) {
  return arr.map((e, i, ar) => {
    if (e === ar[i + 1] || (e[0] && e[0] === ar[i + 1])) {
      return [e, e[1] + 1]
    }
    return e;
  })
}
```

Some example input and output:

```js
// input  [3, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 7, 1]
// output [3,[2,2],5,[1,2],7,1]

// input  [1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
// output [[1,3], 2, 1]
```

Comment: I dont know how do this with reduce

Comment: Not quite clear about the question! Want to group similar items?

Comment: yes, I want to group elements if they are near

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the array and if the value is equal the last value, take an array and increment the counter.

```js
const
    getGrouped = array => array.reduce((r, v, i, { [i - 1]: last }) => {
        if (v === last) {
            if (!Array.isArray(r[r.length - 1])) r[r.length - 1] = [r[r.length - 1], 1];
            r[r.length - 1][1]++;
        } else {
            r.push(v);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(getGrouped([3, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1]));
console.log(getGrouped([2, 2, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: Even if it works, it looks like ancient Aramaic text. Code should be immediately understandable especially if it's few lines long. There is no point in sharing solutions like this one in a knowledge sharing platform. This is just entropy.

Comment: this work not fine. if array = [2,2,2,3] after reduce we get = [2,[2,2],3] First element ignored

Comment: @AlexLatro sorry, should work now. the counter was wrong initialized.

Comment: Very cool - hadn't seen `{ [i - 1]: last }` used like that before - handy way to grab previous element

Comment: I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around that `{ [i - 1]: last }` bit. Can anyone explain to me what's happening there? It's in the slot for source array parameter, right, so how does passing an object instead of a variable name there work?

Comment: @Mr.X, `[i - 1]` is a computed property and because it's a number, it can not be used as variable, so it is renamed to `last`. the destruturing takes place with an array and the result is a variable `last` with the element of the last index.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks, now I get it. It's just plain old restructuring with an alias. It just looks out of place because we don't normally think of arrays as special objects with numeric keys. Clever!

Answer (score 1):

Thank, Joseph Cho - answer is:

```
function splitCounts(arr) {
  let res = [];
  let count = 1;

  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === arr[i+1]) {
      count++;
    } else {
      res.push([arr[i], count]);
      count = 1;
    }
  }

  return res;
}

// [[3,1],[2,2],[5,1],[1,2],[7,1],[1,1]]
console.log(splitCounts([3,2,2,5,1,1,7,1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactored [Nina Scholz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61756370/1366033) with longer variable names, comments, and slightly different control of flow:

```js
const combineAdjacentElements = array => array.reduce((acc, val, i) => {
    // if cur is different from prev value, add raw number
    if (val !== array[i - 1]) {
      acc.push(val)
      return acc
    }

    // if first repetition, replace val with grouped array
    if (typeof acc.at(-1) === 'number') {
        acc[acc.length - 1] = [val, 2];
        return acc
    }

    // if multiple repetition, increment counter in grouped array
    acc.at(-1)[1]++;
    return acc;
}, []);


const output = combineAdjacentElements([3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 7, 1])

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 0))
// [3,[2,3],5,[1,2],7,1]
```

#### Further Reading

- [Check whether variable is number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1303646/1366033)
- [How the get the last element in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69563549/1366033)
- [How to replace the last index value in array javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48744911/1366033)

Answer (score -2):

Just use `Array.reduce()`
   to get that.